# How to apply multiple templates in XSLT?

Tags: xml, templates, xslt

This is my input XML:

```
    <root xmlns:og="http://www.example.com" xmlns:dc="http://www.example.com" >
        <hits>
            <hits>
                <_index>indexname</_index>
                <_type>indextype</_type>
                <_source>
                    <keywords>keywords-NOT-PROVIDED</keywords>
                    <secureFlag>false</secureFlag>
                    <description>How do you make sure your search and big data applications are well-maintained? How to free IT staff&apos;s time to focus more on business goals? Watch our expert address the top 5 managed services questions asked by customers.</description>
                    <connectorSpecific>
                        <discoveredBy>http://www.example.com/enterprise-search-case-studies</discoveredBy>
                        <xslt>false</xslt>
                        <pathFromSeed>LL</pathFromSeed>
                        <md5>WVBM5NDACLWRN4OSXRCQUA5RJA</md5>
                    </connectorSpecific>
                    <title>Do I Need Managed Services for My Search and Big Data Applications?</title>
                    <url>http://www.example.com/big-data-search-managed-services-questions</url>
                    <UD>http://www.example.com/big-data-search-managed-services-questions</UD>
                    <size>21467</size>
                    <displayurl>http://www.example.com/big-data-search-managed-services-questions</displayurl>
                    <UE>http://www.example.com/big-data-search-managed-services-questions</UE>
                    <submitTime>2016-07-21T22:55:00+0000</submitTime>
                    <newContent>Site Map Terms, privacy and cookie</newContent>
   <T>Do I Need Managed Services for My Search and Big Data Applications?</T>
                    <sourceType>heritrix</sourceType><U>http://www.example.com/big-data-search-managed-services-questions</U>
                    <sourceName>PIB</sourceName>
                    </_source>
                <_id>http://www.example.com/big-data-search-managed-services-questions</_id>
                <_score>1</_score>
            </hits>
    <hits>
    </root>
```

This is the XSLT that I am applying:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <GSP>
            <xsl:attribute name="VER">
                <xsl:value-of select="3.2" />
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:for-each select="root">
                <TM>
                    <xsl:value-of select="(floor(took) div floor(1000))" />
                </TM>

                <RES>

                    <M>
                        <xsl:value-of select="floor(hits/total)" />
                    </M>
                    <xsl:for-each select="hits/hits">
                        <xsl:variable name="var1_resultof_first" as="node()"
                            select="_source" />

                        <R>
                            <xsl:attribute name="N">
                            <xsl:number format="0" level="single" />
                            </xsl:attribute>

                            <U>
                                <xsl:sequence
                                    select="xs:string(xs:anyURI(fn:string($var1_resultof_first/url)))" />
                            </U>
                            <UE>
                                <xsl:sequence
                                    select="xs:string(xs:anyURI(fn:string($var1_resultof_first/url)))" />
                            </UE>
                            <UD>
                                <xsl:sequence
                                    select="xs:string(xs:anyURI(fn:string($var1_resultof_first/url)))" />
                            </UD>

                            <T>
                                <xsl:choose>

                                    <xsl:when test="highlight/T">
                                        <xsl:for-each select="highlight/T">

                                            <xsl:sequence select="fn:string(.)" />

                                        </xsl:for-each>
                                    </xsl:when>

                                    <xsl:when test="fn:string($var1_resultof_first/T)">
                                        <xsl:sequence select="fn:string($var1_resultof_first/T)" />
                                    </xsl:when>

                                    <xsl:otherwise>
                                        <xsl:sequence
                                            select="xs:string(xs:anyURI(fn:string($var1_resultof_first/url)))" />
                                    </xsl:otherwise>
                                </xsl:choose>
                            </T>
                            <!-- <T> <xsl:sequence select="fn:string($var1_resultof_first/T)" 
                                /> </T> -->
                            <S>
                                <xsl:for-each select="highlight">
                                    &lt;b&gt;... &lt;/b&gt;
                                    <xsl:sequence select="fn:string(.)" />
                                    &lt;b&gt; ...&lt;/b&gt;
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </S>

                            <CRAWLDATE>
                                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(_source/submitTime,'T')" />
                            </CRAWLDATE>
                        </R>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </RES>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </GSP>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You can see the size element in my input XML.

```
<size>21467</size>
```

I want to apply this template for my size element(size template)

```
<xsl:template match="size">
    <HAS>
        <C SZ="{format-number(. div 1000, '0k')}"/>
    </HAS>
</xsl:template>
```

I am a newbie to XSLT and haven't use multiple template in XSLT. Where should I fit my size template in my original XSLT so that it can be applied on the size parameter? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where in the output do you want it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To minimize the example to the problem at hand, consider the following stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <GSP>
        <xsl:for-each select="hits/hits">
            <R>
                <UD>
                    <xsl:value-of select="_source/UD" />
                </UD>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="_source/size"/>
                <UE>
                    <xsl:value-of select="_source/UE" />
                </UE>
            </R>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </GSP>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="size">
    <HAS>
        <C SZ="{format-number(. div 1000, '0k')}"/>
    </HAS>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GSP>
   <R>
      <UD>http://www.example.com/big-data-search-managed-services-questions</UD>
      <HAS>
         <C SZ="21k"/>
      </HAS>
      <UE>http://www.example.com/big-data-search-managed-services-questions</UE>
   </R>
</GSP>
```

Comment: Thanks. Will try this and let you know :)

Answer (score 2):

Within the `<xsl:for-each select="hits/hits">` loop, you could use

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="_source/size" />
```

at whatever point you wanted to use the size template.